# Cartoon fantasy film with magical or elemental stones/crystals

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

It probably was a feature film, animated (Western style/cartoon), released before or in early 2000s, set in medieval times, girl protagonist and an evil witch or magician antagonist.

The plot was to collect these magical or elemental crystals, there was a race between the good and the evil to do it and in the end the bad uses the stones and brings destruction.

There was also going behind a waterfall for one, castles and dungeons, maybe some bow and arrow action (not sure on that one).

I've been looking for this for like 10 years now...  all of these details are uncertain but the crystal stuff is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The dreamstone. This was haunting me as well. Loved it as a child. Hope it's the same one that you are looking for.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is the answer?

Comment: The series? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreamstone

Answer (score -2):

What about "Final Fantasy: Legend of the Crystals" ? Some hints are matching your description.
https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_Legend_of_the_Crystals

Or "The Dreamstone" ?

Comment: Can you say which parts match?

Comment: And if you have two answers, post them as two.

Comment: Hi there. First of all, unless those two movies are related, may I suggest you split that into two separate answers? You might also want to explain what matches, by providing a summary, clips or something. You can do so in an [edit]. Cheers :)